# Dropdown appears based on prior dropdown with JQuery selector

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to do a round-about way of having dependent drop-down boxes.  I'm hoping to accomplish this with a JQuery selector.

Basically, I'm going to have 1 drop down which lists countries, then if, and only if, United States is selected, I'll have another dropdown appear showing states.

Is there a selector/filter I can use in JQuery to basically say if this dropdown = this value, make the other one appear?

Like a

```
 $("select[option=United States]").change(function() {
      $("#newdropdown").fadeIn();
 });
```

or something like that...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `change()` handler, and then test for the value inside:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "something") {
        $("#newdropdown").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#newdropdown").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/BwuPc/

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the fiddle creation too!

Comment: Haha, nothing better than a client changing their mind and not needing it... either way, awesome help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that instead you can check for the particular condition inside first dropdown's `change` event and then show/hide second dropdown. Try this

```
$("select#country").change(function() {
      if(this.value == "United States"){
          $("#newdropdown").fadeIn();
      }
      else{
          $("#newdropdown").fadeOut();
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("select").change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "United States"){
        $("#newdropdown").fadeIn();   
    }
});
```